# Can't Change the innerHTML of a Table Cell

Tags: javascript, html

I've been having trouble trying to use .innerHTML to change the text inside of table cells.  I want to change the plain text in the cell to a link when one of the radio buttons that I've created is checked.  The relevant code is below:

HTML:

```
 ...<td id="header1" style="width: 80px; text-align:center">Column 1</th>... 


 <div id="testButtons">
        <input type="radio" name="on/off" onclick="showLinks()" value="off" id="off" checked="">
            <label for="off">Function Off</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="on/off" onclick="showLinks()" value="on" id="on">
            <label for="on">Function On</label>
 </div>
```

And Javascript:

```
function showLinks(){ 
if(document.getElementById("on").checked){
    document.getElementById("header1").innerHTML("<a id='headerLink1' href='#' onclick='selectColumn()'>Column 1</a>");
}
```

}

When I test it, I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'innerHTML' of object #HTMLTableCellElement is not a function.

I don't know why, because it seems like this should work, at least according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897.aspx) ("However, to change the content of a particular cell, you can use innerHTML.").

Any help would be appreciated,
           Thanks

Comment: And _is not a _function_ means nothing to you? It's an attribute, so don't use it as if it were a function ...

Comment: You also have an error in your HTML: you open a `<td>` but close it with `</th>`.

Comment: Please stop embedding "onclick" tags in your html. http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Answer (score 4):

`innerHTML` is not a method but a DOM attribute (officially called a `DOMString`). You should do:

```
document.getElementById("header1").innerHTML = "<a id='headerLink1' href='#' onclick='selectColumn()'>Column 1</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've forgot to close your < td >.

It may also be your problem.

```
<td id="header1" style="width: 80px; text-align:center">Column 1 </td></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

> document.getElementById("header1").innerHTML(" href='#' onclick='selectColumn()'>Column 1");

This is not valid because innerHTML is not a method.
You should set its value like this:

> document.getElementById("header1").innerHTML = *some value*

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the onclick to onchange and fix some html mistakes.

```
<table>
<td id="header1" style="width: 80px; text-align:center">Column 1</td>
</table>

 <div id="testButtons">
     <input type="radio" name="onoff" onchange="showLinks()" value="off" id="off" checked="" />
            <label for="off">Function Off</label> 
     <input type="radio" name="onoff" onchange="showLinks()" value="on" id="on" />
            <label for="on">Function On</label>
 </div>

<script>
function showLinks(){ 
   if(document.getElementById("on").checked){
        document.getElementById("header1").innerHTML ="<a id='headerLink1' href='#' onclick='selectColumn()'>Column 1</a>";
    }
}
</script>
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C26MN/