# Not able to pass class attribute in innerhtml for td tag Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have started working on html and javascript and wanted to have some dynamic rows. But whenever I try to set cell.innerHTML with td tag along with class attributes, I am able to add rows but the class attribute is not getting set.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, thead, td {
border:1px solid black;
}


.editMe{

color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</br></br>
<table id="simpleEditableTable" >
<thead>
   <tr>
       <th>testId</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
        <td class="editMe">1.01</td>    
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td class="editMe">1.02</td>    
   </tr>   
</tbody>   
</table>

<p id="para">See</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<td style="color:red">helo</td>';
  
              var table = document.getElementById("simpleEditableTable");
              var row = table.insertRow(-1);
              var cell = row.insertCell(0);
              cell.innerHTML='<td class="editMe">Not working</td>';

           var para = document.getElementById("para");
           para.innerHTML='<p style="color:red">working</p>';
              //tried below ones too
             // cell.innerHTML="<td class='editMe'>helo</td>";
  
  
  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFr57.png)

Tried going through different stackover flow links: [Source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322119/cant-change-the-innerhtml-of-a-table-cell)

Tried similar with different tags like p tag and its working for me.

Expecting to learn how can I pass class attribute in td tag while setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set the cell's `outerHTML` or the row's `innerHTML` to modify the `<td>` element itself.

```js
cell.outerHTML = '<td class="editMe">Some text</td>';
```

Here, it is more appropriate to set the `textContent` and use `.classList.add` to change the class.

```js
let cell = row.insertCell(0);
cell.classList.add('editMe');
cell.textContent = 'Some text';
```

Comment: I used this and it worked like charm Thanks
cell.classList.add('editMe');
           cell.innerHTML = '<td>Not working</td>'

Answer (score 0):

cell.innerHTML= `<td class="editMe">Not working</td>` ;

Use this `` instead not the ‘’ to enclose your text, since it’s an html tag and not a string